# Best way to test for existence of a variable in Python

Tags: python

I am reading a million plus files to scrape out some data.  The files are generally pretty uniform but there are occasional problems where something that I expected to find is not present.

For example, I expect some sgml code to identify a value I need

```
for data_line in temp  #temp is a list of lines from a file
    if <VARIABLENAME> in data_line:
        VARIABLE_VAL=data_line.split('>')[-1]
```

Later on I use `VARIABLE_VAL`.
But I sometimes get an exception: no line in the file that has

```
<VARIABLENAME>theName
```

To handle this I have added this line after all the lines have been processed:

```
try:
    if VARIABLE_VAL:
        pass
except NameError:
    VARIABLE_VAL=somethingELSE
```

I have seen somewhere (but I can't find it anymore) a solution that looks like

```
if not VARIABLE_VAL:
    VARIABLE_VAL=somethingELSE
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just initialize your variable to its default value before the loop:

```
VARIABLE_VAL = somethingELSE
for dataline in temp: ...
```

this way, `VARIABLE_VAL` will keep its initial, default value unless bound to something else within the loop, and you need no weird testing whatsoever to ensure that.

Comment: Thanks Alex, so given that you gave the answer the construct I imagined was just that, imagination

Answer (score 4):

Alex's solution is correct. But just in case you do want to test if a variable exists, try:

```
if 'VARIABLE_VAL' in locals():
    ....
```

Comment: What about if 'VARIABLE_VAL' not in locals() - this is a great answer because now I have something new to play with. I mean now I get to learn what locals is and can do for me Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is also globals() which contains variables from the global namespace. Take a look here for some more info: http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/dialect_locals.html
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is really neat and I see that it deserves some poking around